# VB.Net USB interface

Tags: usb

I have developed software that connects to my inverter to control everything it does. This works via RS-232. This works well. Now a new model of the inverter has come out that has only USB. I want to modify my software to communicate to the inverter using USB but I can not find any simple sample code that shows how to connect to hardware using USB. I have read that there is no native USB control in VB.Net. I found this site http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm but it does not show how to send and receive a command like when using RS-232.

I hope somebody can help as it seems impossible using VB.

Comment: It is possible this device has a special driver that can create a virtual COM port for this device.

Comment: Nope. I have the com port part working, I now need a sample of talking to a device via native USB and not via a serial device please.